# Booleans not working simultaneously

Tags: java, swing, boolean, output, keylistener

I have been creating a test program to test how movement on an angle may possibly work, and even though this is not where my problem lies, it is the program to which my problem/confusion is in. This error(?) does not affect the way my program works unless a user wants to key mash every key to see what happens and that is exactly what I did...

I have a key listener which, on each key press and key release, sets a boolean in an array:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  int key = e.getKeyCode();
  int a = KeyEvent.VK_LEFT; // int value of 37
  int b = KeyEvent.VK_UP; // 38
  int c = KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT; // 39
  int d = KeyEvent.VK_DOWN; // 40

  int aa = KeyEvent.VK_G; // 71
  int bb = KeyEvent.VK_H; // 72

  if(key == a || key == b || key == c || key == d) {
    player.setKeyValue(key - 37, true); // keyReleased is exactly the same but with a false
  }
  if(key == aa || key == bb) {
    player.setKeyValue((key - 71) + 4, true);
  }
}
```

I had my panel draw which keys were getting pressed, and I noticed that not all the keys I were pressing were getting drawn onto the screen. I was majorly confused thinking that it had something to do with the buffered image being too small, so I double checked that and strangely it wasn't. I decided to print all booleans in the array to the console and I found out that, indeed, some keys were actually not getting pressed when physically they were.

Here is some of the output I had received when pressing different keys together:

```
// booleans are in order: Left, up, right, down, g, h
true, false, true, false, false, true
true, false, true, false, true, true
true, false, true, false, false, false
```

I'm not sure why this is happened, but I'm getting the feeling that it has something to do with the amount of memory the JVM can hold at a given time.

Though this poses no real obstacle for me, it would be nice to know how and why this occurs?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood right but if you are actually pressing multiple keys at once then you should be aware that there a limitations on detecting single key presses/releases with "normal" keyboard hardware. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_technology#Keyboard_switch_matrix and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29. It is also imaginable at least one very small buffers may be involved in the keyboard, or in the keyboard driver,or the OS (http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsNT/RegistryTips/Hardware/KeyboardBufferSize.html) etc. which overflows.

Comment: Correct, I am trying to press all/multiple keys at once. So I was slightly correct that it had something to do with the JVM Memory? Or is overflowing something different? - I love this site. I can search an answer for anything. :D

Answer (score 5):

I seriously doubt it has anything to do with the amount of memory the JVM can hold at a given time.

It's hard to say what the best approach is to do what you want.

Consider something like:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  int key = e.getKeyCode();  
  int keyIndex = -1;

  switch(key)
  {
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:  keyIndex = 0; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:    keyIndex = 1; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: keyIndex = 2; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:  keyIndex = 3; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_G:     keyIndex = 4; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_H:     keyIndex = 5; break;
    default:
      System.out.format("Unexpected KeyCode [%d]\n", key);
      break;
  }

  if(keyIndex != -1){ player.setKeyValue(keyIndex, true); }
}
```

This approach gets rid of a lot of the cruft, and also attempts to notify you if you're getting unexpected keys.  Without knowing more, it's hard to give you a better answer, but the one I proposed certainly isn't the best -- it's just a step in debugging.  My guess is something like an ArrayList of KeyEvents or Integers (corresponding to KeyCodes) would probably be a better choice.

You could edit this to *always* display the keycode as well, so you could immediately see what keycode was generated.

Comment: +1 but this question isn't answerable without an SSCCE, pressed released is a standard setting in Native OS for key repeating, Java only to use this (Native OS) property

Comment: Like a [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) where I can stack up items, and poll them as needed? I've seen this be used when I was sifting through code elsewhere. I believe you are on the right track, and I would certainly tick it as the answer, however this question seems to be more of an open discussion...

Comment: -1 Whatever the issue is, this doesn't deal with it.  It's really just a refactor of the code in the question; other than the error message in the default case, which the OP probably doesn't want anyway.

Comment: @DavidWallace, optimizing the code, elimining cruft, and including debug messages is often the first step to finding errors in your code you didn't expect.  It's hard to say what the issue *actually is* without more debugging information.  This is a very surprising response from 12k rep...

Comment: That's what comments are for, not answers.  An answer is for answering the question.  A comment is for eliciting more information, to help towards answering the question.